# Get attribute of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a div, in a div, in a div and I am trying to access the attribute `food` of the extern div through the most intern div. How can I do that?

I commented in the code, I'm trying to alert 'banana'.

```js
//alert($('.animals').attr('food')); //alerts banana

//alert($('.mammals').parent().attr('food')); //alerts banana

//alert($('.monkeys').parent().parent().attr('food')); //doesn't alert banana
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animals" food="banana">
  <div class="mammals">
    <div class="monkeys">
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to change in your third example `.mammals` for `.monkeys`

Comment: Done. I'm looking for a better way than writing .parent() for multiple times. What if I have 100 divs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `closest()` to get to specific parent element of a child element
:

```
alert($('.mammals').closest(".animals").attr('food')); 
alert($('.monkeys').closest(".animals").attr('food')
```

See [**closest() in Jquery DOCS here**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use parents for multiple levels:

```
$('.monkeys').parents('.animals').attr('food')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `closest`

```
alert($('.monkeys').closest(".animals").attr("food"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use closet() or parentsUntil(). With parentsUntil, you can even select multiple parents

```
alert($('.monkeys').parentsUntil(".animals").attr("food"))
```